# C# Why is my named pipe read() method not blocking?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ipc, named-pipes, blocking

I have a method in which I intend to use namedPipeServerStream.Read() to read messages multiple times.  The pipe is started with the Asynchronous property set to true, because I don't want the wait for connection to block. Reading the Microsoft documentation however and trying other examples, it seems that the Read() method is supposed to block when called, until there is data in the pipe to be read.
The pattern that I'm using is to create the pipe, and when a connection is made call a method that utilizes the Read() method.  The Read() is in a while loop until the IsMessageComplete property returns true.  At that point the input is processes, and the method is called again to Read() another time.
My expectation was for the subsequent Read() calls, when no data is int he pipe, since the message was complete that it would block on the call to Read(), and once data was avail, the Iscomplete property would become false, until all of the data is read out. 
In my code, on the subsequent Read() calls, it does not block.  The read just returns 0 bytes and continues on.
This from     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

> Calling the Read method blocks until count bytes are read or the end
>   of the stream is reached. For asynchronous read operations, see
>   BeginRead and EndRead.

Also using this tutorial https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/06/23/basics-of-working-with-pipes-in-c-net-part-4-basic-conversation-with-messages/ as an example, and changing the pipes to **PipeOption.Asynchromous** i find that the Read() method seams to block until data is available.
By the way, I think I can make it work by periodically polling the pipe with reads, but I'm trepidatious about employing that method if I'm not sure what going on.
Here's a skeleton of my code.

```
void pipeServerMethod()
{
         using (NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, /* "test-pipe"*/ PipeDirection.InOut,
                1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            {

                var asynchResult = namedPipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(null, null);

                if (asynchResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(maxWait))
                {
                    namedPipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(asynchResult);



                    while (remainingAttemps > 0)
                    {

                        newInput = readMessage(namedPipeServer);

                        processReceivePipeInput(newInput, mType, allReadsComplete);


                    }
                }
    }
}


public static string readMessage(NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer)
    {

        int readVals; 
        string completedLine = null;
        string messageChunk = string.Empty;
        byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[30];
        do
        {

            readVals = namedPipeServer.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
            messageChunk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBuffer);
            completedLine = completedLine + messageChunk;
            //messageBuilder.Append(messageChunk);
            messageBuffer = new byte[messageBuffer.Length];
        }
        while (!pipetimerExpired && !namedPipeServer.IsMessageComplete);


        return completedLine;

    }
```

Comment: *"Calling the Read method blocks until count bytes are read or the end of the stream is reached"* I'm assuming you are reaching the end of the stream, so it returns immediately. I think the Microsoft samples assume that there is data to be read from the pipe when `Read` is called and will block until it reads the count or the EOS is encountered.

Comment: I'm not sure that's it.  I've tried this example, in which the Read() is called several times.  Each time it read all the data, then IsComplete=true.  When Read is called again on the pipe even the IsComplete=true, it blocks until there's data in the pipe to read, at which time IsComplete=false, until that message is complete. 
 https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/06/23/basics-of-working-with-pipes-in-c-net-part-4-basic-conversation-with-messages/